# How can I expand my .contextMenu preview to fullscreen on tap of preview?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-ontapgesture

I am trying to make my SwiftUI .contextMenu preview, in a forEach view, to be tappable and expandable. Like for example the Apple Stocks app, when I hold a news link, the preview shows up and I am able to tap it to make it expand to fullscreen. I would like to duplicate this behavior, but I don't get how I can do this.

I have tried searching for this but I can't find anything on this. Here is my code for the contextMenu:

```
if !vm.StockNews.isEmpty {
    ForEach(vm.StockNews, id: \.self) { news in
        if let url = URL(string: news.link) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("\(news.title)")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5))
                    .lineLimit(4)
                
                Text("\(news.description)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(5)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                
                Text("\(vm.formattedTimeAgo(from: news.pubDate))")
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5))
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            
            .onTapGesture {
                isPresentingWebView = true
            }
            
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentingWebView) {
                SafariWebView(url: url)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            
            
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action: {
                    UIPasteboard.general.string = news.link
                }) {
                    Text("Kopier lenke")
                    Image(systemName: "link")
                }
                
            } preview: {
                SafariWebView(url: url)
                
            }
            
            
        } else {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("\(news.title)")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding(5)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                
                Text("\(news.description)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(5)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                
                Text("\(news.pubDate)")
                    .padding(5)
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
        
    }
} else {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("Ingen nylige nyheter")
            .font(.title2.bold())
        
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding(.top, -15)
    .padding(.bottom, 30)
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
}
```

And here is the code for the `SafariWebView`:

```
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct SafariWebView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SFSafariViewController {
        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

How could I be able to make my contextMenu preview be tappable and expandable to fill the screen like in the `.fullScreenCover()`.

Comment: What do you mean by contextMenu preview? You would like to have a web preview in full screen?

Comment: No, I would like to have a normal contextMenu that has a preview and if I tap that preview, then the web view I am previewing goes to fullscreen rather than just closing the contextMenu. Like in for example some of Apples Apps, there are some links and I you open the contextMenu, and tap on the preview of the web view, the you open it to fullscreen. this is what I would like to replicate. Is that more understandable?

Comment: I guess so, but I think you need to go for a custom solution to do that.

Comment: Hmmmmm. That's annoying! Why can't Apple just add a way to do it when they are using across their own apps?

Comment: I can try doing it later.

Comment: I've tried it actually but I encountered a few issues... Do you know how to override the default Done button action in the Safari Web View for instance?

Comment: Do you mean remove the button or change the action of the button? But I would think that you might have to have a custom webView rather then using the default safari webView.

Comment: Change the action of the button I mean. Because, when I open it in a custom View using overlay it does not disappear if I press the Done button. It only disappears if using the fullScreenCover.

Comment: I see. Could you maybe try something like this: 
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SFSafariViewController {
let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
vc.delegate = context.coordinator
return vc
}
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
Coordinator(self)
}
class Coordinator: NSObject, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
let parent: SafariWebView
init(_ parent: SafariWebView) {
self.parent = parent
}
func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
// Action here:
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with was an overlay with some buttons on top of it. I hope you like the result. I used a geometry reader to get the size of the view and use it to expand the WebView to full screen.
By the way, the code to modify the Done Button behavior did not work. That's why I was forced to use the xmark to close the web view when using the overlay at least.
The fullScreenCover can still be used if you prefer though, I tried and it works.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPresentingWebView = false
    @State private var showCustomPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let size = proxy.size
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5))
                    .lineLimit(4)
                
                Text("News")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(5)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                
                Text("Date")
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5))
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .onLongPressGesture {
                showCustomPopover = true
            }
            .overlay {
                if showCustomPopover {
                    VStack {
                        SafariWebView(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974957/how-can-i-expand-my-contextmenu-preview-to-fullscreen-on-tap-of-preview?noredirect=1#comment137490790_77974957")!)
                            .frame(width: isPresentingWebView ? size.width : 250, height: isPresentingWebView ? size.height : 300)
                            .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                                HStack {
                                    if isPresentingWebView {
                                        Button("", systemImage: "xmark") {
                                            withAnimation {
                                                showCustomPopover = false
                                                isPresentingWebView = false
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Button("", systemImage: "arrow.up.left.and.arrow.down.right") {
                                        withAnimation {
                                            isPresentingWebView.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                .offset(x: isPresentingWebView ? 15: -30, y: -30)
                            }
                        
                        if !isPresentingWebView {
                            Button(action: {
                                UIPasteboard.general.string = "Link here"
                            }) {
                                Text("Kopier lenke")
                                Image(systemName: "link")
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background {
                if showCustomPopover {
                    Color.gray.opacity(0.1)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                showCustomPopover = false
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            /*.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentingWebView) {
                SafariWebView(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974957/how-can-i-expand-my-contextmenu-preview-to-fullscreen-on-tap-of-preview?noredirect=1#comment137490790_77974957")!)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }*/
        }
    }
        
}
```

As I said, if you prefer you can still use the fullScreenCover, just by uncommenting it it shows up (you may want to remove the resizing behavior of the overlay too though).

Here's the result:

[image: WebView overlay]

Let me know what you think!

Comment: That is a pretty nice solution, but I would need to have the Menu of the contextMenu. So that the user can copy the URL.  Do you know how you could do that while the customPopover is small?

Comment: Sure thing. You may use a VStack and place buttons or any view really below the web view. Do you want any help with that?

Comment: Sure! Thank you! Is it also possible to add som rounded corners?

Comment: I updated the code with what you wanted. Anyway, buttons alread have rounded corners, but if you want more you could use this modifier applied to the button .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 20))

Comment: I just did! Thank you so much for the help!